# Fade in text android without the need of a button?

Tags: android, textview, android-animation

I have added some fade in text to the opening screen of my app, this is controlled by a button, I am wondering is it possible to have the text or an image fade in automatically upon the app starting? I have searched this a number of times and cannot find a solution.

Comment: Just put all the code that is inside the `onClick` into `onCreate`

Comment: If you want some delay, set up a timer for 5 or so seconds and put it in it's `onFinish`

Comment: This worked perfect guys, I was on the right track I just added a piece of code I didn't need, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Cricket said, I deleted the onclick method and inserted the code within inside the onCreate method, this automatically started the fade in textview.